# MVC3 Webgrid formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pagination, webgrid

I am using Webgrid for paging. Is there a way to access each item? For example, i want to add some links column if the the item of the model meets a certain criteria. 
For example:

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
     /If (item.name == "test")// statement to test condition here{
       grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { name = item.name })),
       }
       else{
       grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { name = item.name })),
        }
        grid.Column("FirstName"),
        grid.Column("LastName"),
        grid.Column("EmailAddress")
    )
```

can this be done with webgrid? if not, what are other alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to put a condition like that inside the `format` parameter itself.  Like this:

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(format: item => 
        (item.name == "test") ?
            Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { name = item.name })
            : Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { name = item.name })
    ))
)
```

Note that, if you need to for a more complex scenario, you can also put an anonymous function inside the `format` lambda.  It should return an `MvcHtmlString` (as in `ActionLink`, etc):

```
grid.Column(format: item => 
{
    if (item.name == "test")
    {
        return Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { name = item.name });
    }
    else
    {
        return Html.ActionLink("Detail", "Detail", new { name = item.name });
    }
})
```

Comment: Say I want to have 3 Actionlinks in the same cell (only one with condition), how will I do this?

Comment: @jpo you can combine them using `return Html.Raw( Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Link1").ToHtmlString() + Html.ActionLink("Link2", "Link2").ToHtmlString());`.  I'm not sure if that's the "correct" way, though.